# Can I get clarification of what a "data structure that is a list of lists"?

Tags: python, list

"Build a data structure that will be a list of lists. The lists in the structure will consist of one alphabetic character and then place holders for the number of times that letter is used as the first letter in a word, the number times used as the last letter in word and the sum of these two values."

Given this instruction, I am extremely confused on what is to be expected. Is a place holder just another empty list? So for example the code would look like this:

```
listOfLists = [[],[],[],[]]
```

`list[0]` would be the alphabetic character
`list[1]` would be the number of times it's used as the first letter
`list[2]` would be the number of times it's used as the last letter
`list[3]` would be the sum of the two values

This is how I envision it, but it just seems overly complicated to me. Can someone dumb it down for a beginner? Thanks.

Also can we just increment the number with `line[1] += 1`if it is initialized with 0s?

edit: my wording was shit thanks to the professor but someone explained exactly what I meant below thanks

Comment: Do you have any example input & output?

Comment: I do not. The goal of this is to track how many times a letter is recurring in the first and last spots.

Comment: This looks like you're asking a question about your instructor's (or textbook's) use of the English language, not about Python. I have trouble seeing how it's on-topic here; our rules ask for question to be clearly asked, narrow and specific; the *whole problem* here is that you have something that's expressed unclearly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I thought it was a concept I wasn't grasping. Sometimes when we know less than others a simple thing can seem indecipherable.

Answer (score 0):

I think your understanding is correct and the structure would be:

```py
list_of_lists = [['a', 0, 0, 0], ['b', 0, 0, 0], ...]
```

or

A list of lists containing the letter and the stats about it, for example, the number of times it appeared as the first or last letter.

And you can increment a value if it is already set to `0`.

Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: This makes much more sense. My thinking was close but this example makes it much more clear!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble understand what the quote is saying as well, so a bit more context would be nice.
But after rereading it a few times, this is what I understand it to mean:

```py
# A list of words to work with. It didn't explicitly say that this existed but it seemed to imply it.
words = ["apple", "banana", "quince", "vanilla"]
# Then build the multidimensional list:
list_of_lists = []
for letter in "abdcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
    firsts = len([1 for w in words if w[0] == letter])
 # this is equivalent to 
# l = []
# for w in words:
#     if w[0] == letter:
#        l.append(1)
# firsts = len(l)
# Although since the idea was to get it into one line, instead of appending to a list we would take the faster and cheaper rout of incrementing a counter like this:
# firsts = 0
# for w in words:
#     if w[0] == letter:
#        firsts += 1
    lasts = len([1 for w in words if w[-1] == letter])
    list_of_lists.append([letter, firsts, lasts, firsts + lasts])

# list_of_lists should now be something like this:
[['a', 1, 2, 3], ['b', 1, 0, 1] , ['c', 0, 0, 0]] # etc
```

Of course I could be completely wrong, but that's my take on it.
One more thing. Instead of doing `w[0] == letter` and `w[-1] == letter` I think you could do `w.startswith(letter)` and  `w.endswith(letter)`. It doesn't make much of difference with only one letter, but it sure is easier if you're checking with strings of multiple letters. `startswith()` is especially usefully for search bars, for example.

Comment: This was extremely helpful and exactly what I think is expected. Yet my question is why is the else statement included?

Comment: @kingk The answer is, No reason. I'm not sure why I even put that in there :) Probably because I was thinking that the little `truevalue if expression else falsevalue` required an else option (like in C). I'll take it out of the answer.